# Create a 1 minute countdown timer that counts to zero, resets 4 times and stops using PIC18F46K20?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, countdowntimer

Any ideas as to how i would go about this using MPLAB C18?

```
intCLKsecs++; //Should increase by one every second on every 
InitSecs = 60; //Initialised time for a single korfball half
timeLeft = korf_InitSecs-korf_intCLKsecs; //Time remaining
displayTime(korf_timeLeft);
```

So far I have set-p the TIMER0 to overflow after 1 second by setting `TOCON = 0b0000001`
The only issue is how i can implement the TIMER0 to increment my intCLKsecs variable by one every time the timer overflows, so the variable intCLKsecs should count the number of seconds that have passed. The function displayTime just converts the timeLeft into a clock format using %60.

Answer (score 0):

The timer's interrupt flag will be set on overflow. You can either write an interrupt, or you can poll the flag yourself.

Here's how to poll via software:

```
// Check to see if the timer overflowed after 1 sec
if (INTCONbits.TMR01F)
{
    // Yes, it did. Clear the flag so we do not re-enter until the next second
    INTCONbits.TMR01F = 0;

    // Increment counter
    intCLKsecs++;
}
```

Also, your `T0CON` register has a zero in the 7th bit...you need to see it to one to start the timer (perhaps you have done so elsewhere in the code.)